# error TS2322: Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ApiModelFilter<M>'

Tags: typescript

I try to define some filters where the key of the filter object should be a key of any interfaces thats extends from a Model interface.

The Model Interface defines only an *id* attribute.

When I try to use the ApiModelFilter type in a generic Class just by defining the *id* and a string as value I get the Error from the Title.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem ?

I get this error with Typescript v2.8.3 and v2.6.2

```ts
interface Model {
  id: number;
}

export type ApiModelFilter<M extends Model> = {
  [P in keyof M]?: string
};

interface SomeModel extends Model {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

class GenericModelHandlerClass<M extends Model> {
  get_instance(id: number): void {
    const the_filter: ApiModelFilter<M> = {
      id: 'test'
    };
    ...
  }
}

class SomeModelHandlerClass extends GenericModelHandlerClass<SomeModel> {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, seems like a TypeScript bug (or at least a design limitation).  It's related to [Microsoft/TypeScript#13442](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442) in which someone was surprised that an object literal of type `Partial<U>` with no extra properties is not assignable to `Partial<T>` where `T extends U`.  Now in *that* case, it is not a bug: `T[K]` might be narrower than `U[K]` for some `K`, so you cannot assign `Partial<U>` to `Partial<T>`.  It's not the keys that are the problem; it's the values.

In your case, though, you don't care about the value types like `T[K]` or `U[K]`.  All you care about are the *keys*.  And it sure seems like a literal value of type `{[K in keyof U]?: string}` with no extra properties should be assignable to a variable of type `{[K in keyof T]?: string}` if `T extends U`.  `keyof U` cannot contain any values not present in `keyof T`, so it should work.  (In your code, `M` is acting like `T` and `Model` is acting like `U`.)  The compiler, for some reason, cannot verify that.  You might want to file an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) if you think this use case is compelling.

---

So, workarounds. one way is to do a type assertion:

```
const the_filter = {
  id: 'test'
} as ApiModelFilter<M>; // works
```

You're saying that you know better than the compiler, which seems to be true in this case.

Or you could rearrange your code like this:

```
const the_filter: ApiModelFilter<M> = {};
the_filter.id = 'test'; // also works
```

Here you are originally assigning an empty object to `the_filter` and then adding an `id` property to it.  The compiler *does* recognize that `the_filter` has an optional `id` property, so it allows you to set it.

---

Hopefully one of those works for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer this will help a lot.