# How can I declare a default parameter using Generics

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define the `condition` parameter with a default value that will use the property that is extended on the generic type

```
//animal.ts

export class Animal {
  public id: number;
}
```

```
//someclass.ts

export class SomeClass<T extends Animal> implements SomeInterface<T> {

  public async someMethod(animal: T, condition: Partial<T> = { id: animal.id }): Promise<T | undefined> {
    ...

  }
}
```

But I'm having the error `TS2322: Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial '`

How can I define a default parameter value with generics?

Comment: Maybe check out  [Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442) and [this other question about 2322](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124552/error-ts2322-type-id-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-apimodelfilterm)

Comment: You should probably just use a type assertion like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WolRaw); I don't think there's ever a case where `Pick<T, "id">` isn't assignable to `Partial<T>`, but the compiler can't see it.  A type assertion would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @jcalz I cannot use `Pick` because the parameters could eventually have other properties different to `id`, it's just the default value that needs to have that `id` property.

Comment: @ConnorLow it’s reopened

Comment: Oh I'm not suggesting you use `Pick`, I was just using the type `Pick<T, "id">` to represent the type of `{id: animal.id}` and saying that the compiler cannot see that it's assignable to `Partial<T>`.  This sort of higher-order type analysis is unfortunately out of reach of the compiler.